# How to match any letter in a property while querying?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have written functionality for MongoDB that allows me to search by first or last name, but it only works if the whole name is entered. I'd like it to work if only part of the name is matched as well.

For example, if my search query is `by` then I would like to get the following results:

```
{"firstname": Tony, "lastname": Bobby} , {"firstname": Bonby, "lastname": Johny}
```

This is the code that I wrote:

```
if (req.query.searchText === undefined || req.query.searchText === "") {
    var queryData = { $and:[ {location_id: req.params.location_id}, {role:[constants.ROLES.VET]}, {is_active:true }] }
} else {
    var queryData =
        {
            $and: [
                { $or: [{ first_name: req.query.searchText }, { last_name: req.query.searchText }] },
                { $and:[ {location_id: req.params.location_id}, {role:[constants.ROLES.VET]}, {is_active:true}] }
            ]
        }
}
```

Comment: Enclose your search term within slashes `/` for regular expression searches.. use `i` if you need case insensitive search
For example : /hai/i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var searchText = req.query.searchText.'+';
  var $queryData = 
  {
   $and: [
        { $or: [{ first_name: { $regex: searchText } }, { last_name: {$regex: searchText }}] },
        { $and:[ {location_id: req.params.location_id}, {role:[constants.ROLES.VET]}, {is_active:true}] }
    ]
}
```

Example 'b+' find the string contains one or more b in the string that's why I have appended '+' with your searchText. This is work as expected If your search String contains a single character.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected string it showing error at req.query.searchText.'+';

Comment: sorry, append a string using + operator I used dot(.) replace dot with plus operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **$where** in `MongoDB`.

It's not the easiest way to search by text, but flexible.